# Getting value_counts from partial Categorical column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to try and get `value_counts` from a `Categorical` column (specifically,  containing month information) using `pandas` (v0.23.4). When all categories are present, this works fine:

```
import calendar
import random

import pandas as pd

random.seed(1)

month_names = calendar.month_name[1:]
month_names += month_names

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Month': month_names,
    'Flag': [random.choice([True, False]) for _ in month_names]
})

df1['Month'] = pd.Categorical(
    df1['Month'], categories=calendar.month_name[1:], ordered=True
)
print(df1.groupby('Month')['Flag'].value_counts())
```

As expected prints:

```
Month      Flag 
January    False    2
February   True     2
March      False    2
April      True     2
May        True     2
June       False    2
July       False    1
           True     1
August     False    1
           True     1
September  False    2
October    True     2
November   False    1
           True     1
December   False    2
Name: Flag, dtype: int64
```

However if our `'Month'` column does not contain all of the possible categories, `pandas` throws a `ValueError`. For example:

```
month_names = ['January', 'February', 'March']
month_names += month_names

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Month': month_names,
    'Flag': [random.choice([True, False]) for _ in month_names]
})

df2['Month'] = pd.Categorical(
    df2['Month'], categories=calendar.month_name[1:], ordered=True
)
print(df2.groupby('Month')['Flag'].value_counts())
```

raises:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape (12,) (3,)
```

Is there any way we can get the proper `value_counts` results from the partial data? Ideally this would retain the full set of categories but even without would be a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the observed categories, you can use the `observed`-keyword:

```
print(df2.groupby('Month', observed=True)['Flag'].value_counts())
#Month     Flag 
#January   False    1
#          True     1
#February  True     2
#March     False    2
#Name: Flag, dtype: int64
```

To get all the values in the groupby, you can use a workaround using `crosstab` and then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) using all the categories. To be honest, I'm not sure why the original `GroupBy` gives the error with `value_counts()` (it works fine for other methods), but this works, after using [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to make the `Flag`-columns into a MultiIndex:

```
(pd.crosstab(df2['Month'], df2['Flag'])
.reindex(df2['Month'].cat.categories.tolist(), fill_value=0)
.stack())
#Month      Flag 
#January    False    1.0
#           True     1.0
#February   False    0.0
#           True     2.0
#March      False    2.0
#           True     0.0
#April      False    0.0
#           True     0.0
#May        False    0.0
#           True     0.0
#June       False    0.0
#           True     0.0
#July       False    0.0
#           True     0.0
#August     False    0.0
#           True     0.0
#September  False    0.0
#           True     0.0
#October    False    0.0
#           True     0.0
#November   False    0.0
#           True     0.0
#December   False    0.0
#           True     0.0
```

Comment: This is perfect, thankyou so much. It seems odd to me that `observed=False` basically malfunctions in this way but `observed=True` should be sufficient in my case.